# What is a char* when set equal to ""?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

I am trying to write my own string class for an assignment, and I was wondering how I should treat the argument of "".

For example, if there is a call of:

```
s = myString("")
```

what is the length, and what are the contents of the char* holding the data in my 'myString' class?

Comment: The length is 0, so the char* should not contain anything (that is, char[0] would be NULL)

Comment: (`char[0]` would be 0, not NULL)

Comment: `char[0]` is not a pointer, so it won't be NULL. It's zero

Comment: so would it have a length of 1, char[0] would be 0, and there would be a null-terminated character after that?

Comment: What do you mean by "what is the length" exactly?

Comment: for example: the length of char* "abc" would be 3

Comment: Are you null-terminating the buffer in `myString`? If not, this explains some of the confusion.

Comment: @ErikStryshak: The length of an empty string is zero. If you use 3 bytes to store a 3-character string like `"abc"`, you use 0 bytes to store a 0-character string. If you use 4 bytes to store a 3-character string (for a null terminator), you use 1 byte to store a 0-character string.

Comment: In the case of an empty (C-style) string, `char *str = ""`, `str[0]` is `0`, and that **is** the terminating NUL char. There is no additional NUL char after that. (Note that "NUL" refers to the zero ASCII value, whereas "NULL" in C and C++ is a special pointer value that does not point to a location in memory. It is the former that terminates a C-style string.)

Comment: What are you guys talking about. `char[N]` is a type, and `char[0]` is not allowed (C-style array type must have dimension at least `1`)

Comment: @M.M That's not what anyone was saying... `char* s = ""` effectively results in `char s[1] = { 0 }` (even though the language parser sees it more like `char s[0] = { }`). They were talking about the situation of `s[0]` and not `char[0]`. They were just short-handing the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `char *` passed to you will be a pointer to an "null" terminated list of `char`'s which, most likely, will be a single, immutable `char` whose value is `0` (or "null").

For example...

```
const char* s = "";
char value = *s;
int length = strlen(s);
```

... should result in...

```
s == [compiler defined]
!value == true
length == 0
```

Comment: More specifically a pointer to an immutable `char` whose value is `0`.